# Compare two XML files and get same value in XSLT

Tags: loops, xslt, merge

I have two XML files.

Resource.xml

```xml
<all>
    <response>
        <identifier>1234</identifier>
    </response>
    <response>
        <identifier>5678</identifier>
    </response>
</all>
```

and collection.xml

```xml
<collection>
    <response>
        <datas>1234</datas>
        <datas>202122</datas>
        <identifier>10</identifier>
    </response>
    <response>
        <datas>1234</datas>
        <datas>5678</datas>
        <datas>303132</datas>
        <identifier>11</identifier>
    </response>
</collection>
```

I would like to merge them into a single XML file by listing only the values present in both files as in the following example. The 'line' elements correspond to the Collection 'response'.

```xml
<root>
    <line>
        <id>10</id>
        <refid>1234</refid>
    </line>
    <line>
        <id>11</id>
        <refid>1234</refid>
        <refid>5678</refid>
    </line>
</root>
```

With the following XSL file, the refids are missing. The condition in the loop does not work.

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:variable name="ressource" select="document('../Input/ressource.xml')"/>
    <xsl:template match="collection">
        <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="response">
            <line>
                <xsl:variable name="datas" select="datas"/>
                <id>
                    <xsl:value-of select="identifier"/>
                </id>
                <xsl:for-each select="$ressource/response/identifier[. = $datas]">
                    <refid>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$datas"/>
                    </refid>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </line>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path into the second document should start with `/all/response`, not with `/response`.